# CMFCRibbonGallery Being slow

Tags: c++, mfc, cmfcribbonpanel

I am using the CMFCRibbonGallery control. I have 1 image it in comprised of 350 images total. Each image is 64hX128w. On the initial draw of the control it is slow. Every other time it is fast. I tried adding the 350 images individually at first but found that to be much slower cause it looks to be just making one large image like what I ended up doing. So I am wondering if there is anyway I can make this faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overloading OnDrawPaletteIcon which made me able to draw it much faster and manage the images myself.